# Create Customer Deposit from Sales Order Suitelet 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to create a Customer Deposit from Sales Order in a User Event AfterSubmit function in SuiteScript 2.0, I need the Sales Order to be linked in the Customer Deposit `salesorder` field. I'm getting the following error:

```
"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_FLD_VALUE","message":"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 123456 for the following field: salesorder",
```

Also note that I no SOs appear in that field in the GUI, when I create the Customer Deposit without setting that field. I am working to automate the manual process of creating a Sales Order and selecting Save and Create Deposit from the dropdown beside the Save button.

Any ideas?

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
    // Only run on creation of Sales Orders
    if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE) return;
    var newSO = context.newRecord;
    var sales_order = newSO.id
    var newDeposit = record.create({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
        isDynamic: true,
        defaultValues: {
            entity: customer
        }
    })
    if (sales_order) {
        newDeposit.setValue({
            fieldId: 'salesorder',
            value: sales_order
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe `[sales_order]` as it's a select field? (not worked with customer deposits yet)

Answer (score 2):

In SS1.0 the way is as follows. `soId` is the sales order's internal id:

```
var depRec = nlapiCreateRecord('customerdeposit', { entity: soRec.getFieldValue('entity'), salesorder: soId });
```

Since you are in a sales order after submit event that you've limited to type == 'create' you have to have a newSO so the following should work:

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
    // Only run on creation of Sales Orders
    if (context.type !== context.UserEventType.CREATE) return;
    var newSO = context.newRecord;
    var newDeposit = record.create({
        type: record.Type.CUSTOMER_DEPOSIT,
        isDynamic: true,
        defaultValues: {
            entity: newSO.getValue({fieldId:'entity'}),
            salesorder: newSO.id
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I added the following line, and it shows that the salesorder field is not getting set. Similar debug lines show other fields set, such as customer and cczipcode. Just salesorder is blank. `log.debug("newDeposit: salesorder", newDeposit.getValue({ fieldId: 'salesorder' }))`

Comment: what happens if you save the deposit? Are you sure you're in the afterSubmit phase?

Comment: If you are not getting data you expect on the create, you can put that in a try/catch to see if it's throwing an error. Same can be done with the save()

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating what your script does via the UI. Can you select a Sales Order when creating Customer Deposits?  If you can't select Sales Order in the UI, most of the time you won't be able to do it via script.